# Vuetify timed universal alert component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Good day. I am trying to create a universal alert component that show api errors whenever an api call fails.

I was trying to use setTimeOut  to remove the alert but once the alert shows up once setTimeOut is not reset, so the time it stays on screen varies. I was able to remove setTimeOut and instead let the user simply click on the alert message to close it but the message stays on forever as if the user never clicked on it, which is not ideal.

I want to be able to show my alert for around 5 seconds or so.

How do I change my component to stay on for a set amount of time?

Here's my code:

My App.vue, where my entire application is called trough router. It checks if there's an state that indicates error:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <div class="AppPadding">
        <router-view />
      </div>
    </v-content>
    <div>
      <errorMessages v-if="errorMessage"/>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import errorMessages from "@/components/component/errorMessages";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    errorMessages
  },
  computed: {
    errorType: function() {
      return this.$store.getters.errorType;
    },
    errorMessage: function() {
      return this.$store.getters.errorMessage;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      //
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.AppPadding {
  padding-top: 5%;
}
</style>
```

Right here is my error message component. It gets an error type and message saved in my app states and allows the user to clear the error states when clicked, thus closing the alert component.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-alert
      :value="errorExists"
      type="error"
      transition="slide-y-reverse-transition"
      v-model="errorMessage"
      @click="removeErrors"
    >
      {{ "ERROR: " + this.errorType + " " + this.errorMessage }}
    </v-alert>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    errorType: function() {
      let value = this.$store.getters.errorType;
      if (value != undefined && value != null) {
        return this.$store.getters.errorType;
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    },
    errorMessage: function() {
      let value = this.$store.getters.errorMessage;
      if (value != undefined && value != null) {
        return this.$store.getters.errorMessage;
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    },
    errorExists: function() {
      let value = this.$store.getters.errorMessage;
      if (value != undefined && value != null) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeErrors(){
      this.$store.dispatch('removeErrors')
      console.log('remove errors')
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      //
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this in your current code is to add [`mounted()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) in your error message component in order to make it call the `removeErrors()` method after a timeout of 5 seconds. Here is the code with the additional timeout :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-alert
      :value="errorExists"
      type="error"
      transition="slide-y-reverse-transition"
      v-model="errorMessage"
      @click="removeErrors"
    >
      {{ "ERROR: " + this.errorType + " " + this.errorMessage }}
    </v-alert>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    errorType: function() {
      let value = this.$store.getters.errorType;
      if (value != undefined && value != null) {
        return this.$store.getters.errorType;
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    },
    errorMessage: function() {
      let value = this.$store.getters.errorMessage;
      if (value != undefined && value != null) {
        return this.$store.getters.errorMessage;
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    },
    errorExists: function() {
      let value = this.$store.getters.errorMessage;
      if (value != undefined && value != null) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  },

  /* 
   * =========== only changed here ==========
   *  when mounted, the component fires removeError() after 5000 ms.
   */
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(this.removeErrors, 5000)
  }
  // ========================================

  methods: {
    removeErrors(){
      this.$store.dispatch('removeErrors')
      console.log('remove errors')
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
  //
    };
  }
};
</script>
```